# Change chart legend style

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4.1

I'm using ExtJs pie chart and now I need to change the chart's style. I already changed  **labels** style but now I want to change the legends style.

How can I achieve that? I didn't find any document/question about that.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this silly question, I finally found the solution myself. I should add the `legend` object to the chart:

```
legend: {
    position: 'right',
    labelFont: 'tahoma'
}
```

Simple.